# ngRepeat-ed directives representing fields of external model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Let `obj` be an object in my `$scope` having an initially empty `parts` array property.
I defined a scope function to add empty objects inside the `parts` array, and there's an `ng-repeat`ing directive (over the `parts` array) which in turn contains another `ng-repeat`ing one over the `fields` describing a single `part` instance (for simplicity, only two properties are taken into account, `id` and `description`, but in my actual scenario there are plenty more).
According to the `field`'s `type` property, it is either rendered as a `<select>` or an `<input>` tag. Ideally, the `<select>` should fetch from a list of possible parts, and bind the chosen one (both its `id` and `description` fields) to the current `part` in `obj.parts`, whereas the `description` field should offer a default description the user can further modify. But I can't get it to work. I jotted down [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axedre/cLnzfqxg/1/) to better illustrate my issue.

If I click "Add part" and choose "foo" from the `<select>`, I expect:

1. the first (and only) element in the `$scope.obj.parts` array to change to `{"id":"foo","description":"Foo description"}`;
2. the `<input>` field next to the `<select>` to display the description accordingly;
3. the array element's `description` property to change If I edit the `<input>`.

**Note**: if I change (line 9 of the jsFiddle) the binding from `ng-model="part"` to `ng-model="obj.parts[$index]"`, point `1.` of the previous list works, but only on the array's first element (i.e.: if I add more parts, they all refer to `$scope.obj.parts[0]`) and issues `2.` and `3.` remain (actually, all `<input>`s refer to `$scope.obj.parts[1].description`, for some reason).

Please help, I'm at wit's end. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using the `$parent` scope identifier on both the `obj.parts` array and the outermost `$index` property. jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLnzfqxg/3/).